# Trying to find if a number is a palindrome in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JS and I have a few exercises that I'm trying to solve in order to improve. At the moment, I'm trying to find out if a number is palindrome, and I have this code, but it doesnt seem to work, since I get that all the numbers I insert in the inputs are palindromes.

```
<input type="text" class="screen">
<button type="button" class="btn">Check</button>


 var strg = document.querySelector(".screen").value;
 var pal = strg.split("").reverse("").join("");

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (strg == pal) {
    console.log(strg+" is a palindrome");
  }
  else {
    console.log(strg+" is not a palindrome");
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lw6uk8kb/

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the first two lines inside the handler as well:

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var strg = document.querySelector(".screen").value;
    var pal = strg.split("").reverse("").join("");
    if (strg == pal) {
        console.log(strg+" is a palindrome");
    }
    else {
        console.log(strg+" is not a palindrome");
    }
});
```

else you will always query the same (empty?) value of `.screen`.

Answer (score 1):

Use code as below:

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var strg = document.querySelector(".screen").value;
    var pal = strg.split("").reverse("").join("");
    if (strg == pal) {
    console.log(strg+" is a palindrome");
  }
  else {
    console.log(strg+" is not a palindrome");
  }
})
```

This will work because you will calculate palindrome at moment (after) you click on button. In your code all computation works at once after all scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't update your variables with actual values.
Just move them inside event handler:

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
 var strg = document.querySelector(".screen").value;
 var pal = strg.split("").reverse().join("");
 if (strg == pal) {
   console.log(strg+" is a palindrome");
 } else {
   console.log(strg+" is not a palindrome");
 }
})
```